# Specifying the port when debugging under Ripple?

Tags: multi-device-hybrid-apps

Visual Studio appears to select a port between 4400 and 4444 when running on Ripple.  How can I set this port permanently?  The problem is that the app I'm working on relies on a SQLite database.  When Visual Studio changes the port it effectively starts the application off on a clean slate, so I lose all existing data unless I copy the relevant files from:

C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\VisualStudio\MDA\RPL_UserData\Default\databases\http_localhost_44XX

to

C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\VisualStudio\MDA\RPL_UserData\Default\databases\http_localhost_44YY

Is there any way to force Visual Studio to use a predefined port?  I'm running on Windows 8.1 and building for Android.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently you cannot fix the port no for Ripple. Visual Studio randomly picks port no. between 4400 and 4444. This issue will be fixed in next Visual Studio Tools for Apache Cordova update.

Answer (score 0):

If devalopper connect them app with WebAPI2 (differance domain ) will got issuse cause when ripper run  alway  changeport.

Ps. Connect app with WebAPI2   have to  Enable cross-origin requests for differance domain.
[EnableCors(origins: "http://localhost:4414", headers: "*", methods: "*")]

http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/security/enabling-cross-origin-requests-in-web-apia

Comment: It is quite difficult to understand what you mean.

Comment: I create codova app (mobile app) from Visual Studio 2013. And my app connect with WebAPI2 (Restful) .
When debug  codova app  in vs2013 codova  ripper often change port number in localhost domain.